# PHP - Pull ids from a string and convert to array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on a linking system and the UI will post a hidden string below

```
"artwork:56,artwork:34,music:123"
```

This will represent linking the following media:

- Artwork ID:56
- Artwork ID: 34
- Music ID:123

What I'm trying to figure out is how to feed in the string above and spit out the id's I need.

```
function getArtworkIds($string){
     //Code Needed
}
```

Results [56,34]

Any help would be awesome, Thank you

Comment: explode on coma, loop, explode on colon. if the UI posted a better format it would be quicker (if you have that option)

Comment: I can make it post a different format. I was trying to make one single field to link media. Figured this was a clean way to post back the list

Comment: then send a real array JSON  encoded or serialize()

Comment: Thank you @Dagon I think I'm going to go that route instead. Over thinking this to much. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string  = "artwork:56,artwork:34,music:123";

$a = explode(',',$string);
$ids = array();
foreach($a as $i){
  if(strpos($i,"art") !== false){
    $ids[] = explode(':',$i)[1];
  }
}
var_dump($ids);
```

Output: 56,34

the `!== false` is important, as `strpos` will return `0` since the string starts with `art`. Without the `!== false` check you'd get no results because the `if` would treat the `0` as a boolean false

Comment: why only `art`?  why not simple string compare the whole word?

Comment: Compare `explode()[0]` to `'artwork'`? Could, but it keeps from having to keep a separate variable for the exploded array or calling explode twice...

Comment: you call explode twice anyway, so why not use it

Comment: Yeah on two different objects. By twice I meant within the for loop

Comment: Exactly, creating a separate variable for the second explode, that's why I did it the way I did